# I want to subclass dict and set default values

Tags: python, dictionary, subclass

I have a need to create a special subclass of dict.  In it I want to set default values for a set of keys.

I seem to be failing in finding the correct syntax to do this.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
class NewDict(dict):
    Key1 = "stuff"
    Key2 = "Other stuff"
    NoList = []
    Nada = None
```

I am then instantiating an object like this:

```
PrefilledDict = NewDict()
```

and trying to use something in there:

```
print PrefilledDict['Key1']
```

But it seems that my dictionary is not a dictionary.

What little bit am I missing?

Comment: Why do you need to subclass `dict` for such a task?

Comment: Your class _is_ indeed a dictionary subclass, it just doesn't have the predefined keys and values you wanted in it -- because your class definition is creating class attributes rather than filling in the predefined dictionary entries it sounds like you desire.

Comment: Thank you martineau.  badzil provided what I needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve what you want as such:

```
class NewDict(dict):

    def __init__(self):
        self['Key1'] = 'stuff'
        ...

PrefilledDict = NewDict()
print PrefilledDict['Key1']
```

With your code, you are creating attributes of the NewDict class, not keys in the dictionary, meaning that you would access the attributes as such:

```
PrefilledDict = NewDict()
print PrefilledDict.Key1
```

Comment: Ah.  I think __init__ is probably the way to go indeed.

Comment: If there's a number of items to add, it may be more efficient to use `self.upate(...)` and add them in one big batch.

Answer (score 8):

No subclassing needed:

```
def predefined_dict(**kwargs):
    d = {
        'key1': 'stuff',
        ...
    }
    d.update(kwargs)
    return d

new_dict = predefined_dict()
print new_dict['key1']
```

or just:

```
defaults = {'a':1, 'b':2}
new_dict = defaults.copy()
print new_dict['a']
```

Comment: I agree that no subclassing is needed, however this does not answer the question.

Comment: @badzil I think the question is due to a limited view of the OP so this is probably a valid answer. And in this case it is clearly the preferable approach.

Comment: if all keys are valid Python identifiers (as in OP's case) then `dict(Key1="stuff", Key2="Other stuff")` might be neater than `{'Key1': "stuff", 'Key2': "Other stuff"}`.

Comment: That will work best if I am defining the base dictionary in the same module as the actual data sets, I would prefer to define it elsewhere so that I can keep that sort of template work separate from data storage.

Comment: the edge case for subclassing is for templating default dicts as separate dict instances without having to copy/deepcopy.

Answer (score 3):

[@astynax provided a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10901498/4279) but if you must use a subclass you could:

```
class defaultattrdict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        try: return getattr(self, key)
        except AttributeError:
            raise KeyError(key) #PEP409 from None
```

Then:

```
class NewDict(defaultattrdict):
    Key1 = "stuff"
    Key2 = "Other stuff"
    NoList = []
    Nada = None

PrefilledDict = NewDict()
print(PrefilledDict['Key1']) # -> "stuff"
print(PrefilledDict.get('Key1')) #NOTE: None as defaultdict
```

Note: your code doesn't follow pep8 naming convention.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't being careful in convention for my example.  Thanks.