# I need to append a dictionary to a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Ok, I have a dictionary called food.  food has two elements, both of which are dictionaries themselves, veg and dairy.  veg has two elements  root : Turnip, and stem : Asparagus.  dairy has cheese : Cheddar and yogurt : Strawberry.   I also have a new dictionary fruit which has red : Cherry and yellow : Banana.

```
food['veg']['root'] == 'Turnip'
food['dairy']['cheese'] == 'Cheddar'
```

etc and

```
fruit['red'] == 'Cherry'
```

Now I would like to add the "fruit" dictionary to the "food" dictionary in its entirety, so that I will have:

```
food['fruit']['red'] == 'Cherry'
```

I know that I could do something like this:

```
food['fruit'] = fruit
```

But that seems clumsy.  I would like to do something like

```
food.Append(fruit)
```

But that doesn't do what I need.

(Edited to removed the initial capitals from variable names, since that seemed to be causing a distraction.)

Comment: If by "doesn't do what I need" you mean "is not supported by the language and throws an error", that's correct.  It might look "clumsy" to you but you've already identified the correct solution.

Comment: `Food['Fruit'] = Fruit` seems like exactly the right way to do that. Dictionaries are meant to be indexed in by keys. In this case you have Food, which is a dictionary of string keys, and dictionary values. Why wouldn't you want to set a key on it to the dictionary?

Comment: In Python, and indeed most languages, your variables should start with a lower case.  An uppercase first letter is reserved for class names.

Comment: I would prefer not to double my fruits like that. The dictionary already has a name, I would like for it to be used in the append, if at all possible.

Comment: `a = {}; b = a`.  Is the name of the dictionary `b` or `a`?

Comment: Also note that you can't do something like `Food.Append(Fruit)` because you're only giving one value here but a dictionary always consists of key/value pairs. So when adding new content to a dictionary, you need to specify both the key and the value.

Comment: To be totally clear, a dictionary has no append() method, only an update() method.

Comment: I do understand that there is no .Append, which is why I used the language "something like".

Comment: No doubled fruit? We can do that. `a = 'Fruit' / Food[a] = locals()[a]`.

Comment: @Soviut: Actually the PEP 8 Style Guide doesn't say first-letter-capitalized or `CapWord` style names are _reserved_ for classes, although it does recommend that function and instance variable names be all "lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Food['Fruit'] = Fruit` is the right and proper way *(apart from the capitalized names)*.

As @kindall wisely notes in the comment, there can be several names referencing the same dictionary, which is why one can't build a function that maps the object to its name and uses that as the new key in your `food` dict.

Comment: I would prefer not to double my fruits like that. The dictionary already has a name, I would like for it to be used in the append, if at all possible.

Comment: `a = {}; b = a`.  Is the name of the dictionary `b` or `a`?

Answer (score 4):

I know what you are trying to do. You are trying to avoid [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in python. Sadly python, and many other languages, are very bad at this.

The main issue though is that **You are mixing the names of your variables with the values in your program. It is a common faux pas in many programming languages.**

If you really wanted to do this, the thing you have bound to the `fruit=...` variable would need to know its name.

- You are trying to say, in python "graft this dict onto this other dict".
- Python demands that you say it like "graft this dict onto this other dict, attaching it at `"Fruit"`"
- The only way around this is that the name "Fruit" already exist somewhere. But it doesn't: it only exists in a variable name, which is not in your program.

There are two solutions:

- You could avoid ever creating a `fruit=...` variable, and instead directly graft it only the `"Fruit"` name. So you would only have to type "Fruit" once, but instead of not typing the `somedict["Fruit"]` like you want, we're avoiding typing the variable name. This is accomplished by programming in anonymous style:

  ```
  somedict["Fruit"] = {'red':'apple', 'yellow':'banana'}
  ```

Sadly, python will not let you do this if your construction requires statements; you can only get away with this if you just have a literal. The other solution is:

- You could create a function which does this for you:

  ```
  graft(somedict, "Fruit", {'red':'apple', 'yellow':'banana'})
  ```

Sadly this too would not work if your construction required any kind of statement. You could create a variable `x={'red':...}` or something, but that defeats the whole purpose. The third way, which you shouldn't use, is `locals()`, but that still requires you to refer to the name.

In conclusion, IF you require significant for loops and functions and if statements, what you are trying to do is impossible in python, unless you change the entire way you construct your `fruit=...` dictionary. It would be possible with combinations of multiline lambdas, dictionary comprehensions (`dict((k,v) for k,v in ...)`), inline `IFTRUE if EXPR else IFFALSE`, etc. The danger of this style is that it very quickly becomes hard to read.

It is possible if you are able to express your dictionary as a literal dictionary, or a dictionary comprehension, or the output of a function which you have already written. In fact it's fairly easy (see other answers). Unfortunately the original question does not say how you are building these dictionaries.

Assuming those answers don't answer your question (that is, you are building these in a really complicated manner), you can write "meta" code: code that will make your dictionary for you, and abuse reflection. However the best solution in python is to just try to make your dictionary with iteration. For example:

```
foods = {
    "Fruit": {...},
    "Meats": makeMeats(),
}
for name,data in ...:
    foods[name] = someProcessing(data)
foods.update(dataFromSomeFile)  #almost same as last two lines
```

Comment: Excellent generalization of the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you're using the square brackets?  Because you can represent this data structure with nested literal dictionaries:

```
food = {
    'veg': {
        'red': 'tomato',
        'green': 'lettuce',
    },

    'fruit': {
        'red': 'cherry',
        'green': 'grape',
    },
}
```

Comment: personally I find the square brackets easier to read.  What I use in my actual code depends on the application.

Comment: @SkipHuffman Aren't square brackets for lists, not dictionaries?

Comment: No, a dictionary can be created with {}, but it's updated with square brackets.

Comment: @JeremyPridemore  I use them all the time.  And they are the style described in "Learning Python"  Chapter 8.

Comment: @SkipHuffman: I personally find braces easier to read, since you can see the hierarchical structure.

Comment: I have to agree. When dealing with nested dictionaries, it's much easier to understand the structure with nesting and indenting than line after line of square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do append because a dictionary is not a list: it has no order. What you want to do is update the dictionary with a new key/value pair. You need to use:

```
Food['Fruit'] = Fruit
```

or, alternatively:

```
Food.update({'Fruit': Fruit})
```

An unrelated note: it's not Python coding style to write variables with capitals. `Fruit` would be written as `fruit` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem you have is that your dictionary does not know its own name. Which is normal; generally, any number of names can be bound to a Python object, and no single name is in any way privileged over any others. In other words, in `a = {}; b = a`, both `a` and `b` are names for the same dictionary, and `a` is not the "real" name of the dictionary just because it was assigned first. And in fact, a dictionary has no way to even know what name is on the left side of the variable.

So one alternative is to have the dictionary contain its own name as a key.  For example:

```
fruit = {"_name": "fruit"}
fruit["red"] = "cherry"

food[fruit["_name"]] = fruit
```

Well, that didn't help much, did it? It did in a way, because `fruit` is now not a string any longer in the attachment to the `food` dictionary, so at least Python will give you an error message if you mistype it. But you're actually typing "fruit" even more than before: you now have to type it when you create the dictionary in addition to when you attach it to another dictionary. And there is a fair bit more typing in general.

Also, having the name as an item *in* the dictionary is kind of inconvenient; when you are iterating over the dictionary, you have to write code to skip it.

You could write a function to do the attachment for you:

```
def attach(main, other):
    main[other["_name"]] = other
```

Then you don't have to repeat yourself when you attach the sub-dictionary to the main one:

```
fruit = {"_name": "fruit"}
fruit["red"] = "cherry"

attach(food, fruit)
```

And of course, now you can actually create a dictionary *subclass* that knows its own name and can attach a named subdictionary. As a bonus, we can make the name an *attribute* of the dictionary rather than storing it *in* the dictionary, which will keep the actual dictionary cleaner.

```
class NamedDict(dict):

    def __init__(self, name="", seq=(), **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, seq, **kwargs)
        self.__name__ = name

    def attach(self, other):
        self[other.__name__] = other

food  = NamedDict("food")

fruit = NamedDict("fruit")
fruit["red"] = "cherry"

food.attach(fruit)
```

But we still have one repeat, when the `NamedDict` is initially defined: `food = NamedDict("food")` for example. How do we dispense with that?

It *is* possible, though unwieldy and probably not worth the trouble. Python has two kinds of objects that have an "intrinsic" name: classes and functions. In other words:

```
class Foo:
    pass
```

The above not only creates a variable named `Foo` in the current namespace, the class's name is also conveniently stored in the class's `__name__` attribute. (Functions do something similar.) By abusing classes and metaclasses, we can exploit the underlying machinery to *completely* avoid repeating ourselves—with the *minor* drawback of having to write our dictionaries as though they were classes!

```
class NamedDict(dict):

    class __metaclass__(type):

        def __new__(meta, name, bases, attrs):
            if "NamedDict" not in globals():   # we're defining the base class
                return type.__new__(meta, name, bases, attrs)
            else:
                attrs.pop("__module__", None)  # Python adds this; do not want!
                return meta.NamedDict(name, **attrs)

        class NamedDict(dict):
            def __init__(self, name, seq=(), **kwargs):
                dict.__init__(self, seq, **kwargs)
                self.__name__ = name

            def attach(self, other):
                self[other.__name__] = other

        __call__ = NamedDict
```

Now, instead of defining our dictionaries the usual way, we declare them as subclasses of `NamedDict`. Thanks to the metaclass, subclassing the outer `NamedDict` class actually creates *instances* of the inner `NamedDict` class (which is the same as before). The attributes of the subclass we define, if any, become items in the dictionary, like keyword arguments of `dict()`.

```
class food(NamedDict): pass

class fruit(NamedDict): red = "cherry"

# or, defining each item separately:

class fruit(NamedDict): pass
fruit["red"] = "cherry"

food.attach(fruit)
```

As a bonus, you can still define a `NamedDict` the "regular" way, by instantiating it as a class:

```
fruit = NamedDict("fruit", red="cherry")
```

Be warned, though: the "class that's really a dictionary" is a pretty non-standard idiom for Python and I would suggest that you not ever actually do this, as other programmers will not find it at all clear. Still, this is how it can be done in Python.

Comment: I think subclassing the dictionary is exactly what I need, and actually what I am doing anyway.  This question was from earlier in the day yesterday:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901048/i-want-to-subclass-dict-and-set-default-values   It is the other half of the same problem I am trying to solve.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for defaultdict. It works by adding a new empty dictionary whenever you ask for a new first level type.
Example shown below:

```
from collections import defaultdict

basic_foods = {'Veg' : {'Root' : 'Turnip'}, 'Dairy' : {'Cheese' : 'Cheddar'}}

foods = defaultdict(dict, basic_foods)
foods['Fruit']['Red'] = "Cherry"
print foods['Fruit']
```

Comment: maybe, though this is not what the OP is asking for